# Why doesn't the link go through to the url when clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a link on a contact form which is supposed to refresh a captcha code when clicked. I also have some code that is triggered via jquery that ensures a div stays open by assigning some CSS to a div. Both of these elements work in isolation, but when combined the captcha code doesn't refresh.  I was wondering if anyone could tell me why?

Here's the code on the link:

```
[<a href="?spamprotect=refresh" class="spam">New code</a>]:
```

Here's the php code that refreshes the captcha:

```
if ( ($user['spamprotect'] == "") || ( ( (isset($_GET['spamprotect'])) && ($_GET['spamprotect'] == "refresh")
 ) ) ) {
    $user['spamprotect'] = password_return_random(4);
    $_SESSION['spamprotect'] = $user['spamprotect'];
}
```

And here's the jquery that assigns the CSS to a containing div (at the moment I have this code in the  section :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.spam').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.slidingDiv').css('display', 'block !important');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: because you had prevented its default action..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) "prevents normal behavior" of elements. In your case, the `<a>` is prevented from visiting the URL specified by its `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for that... it makes sense! If I remove that code the css doesn't get applied for some reason? In other words, if my Jquery is: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.spam').click(function() {
        $('.slidingDiv').css('display', 'block !important');
    });
});

Comment: I can't really say the cause unless I can run the code myself. Sorry.

Comment: Many thanks anyway. I've had to find an alternative because there was something else blocking the CSS. :)